# Emberjs click event on a specific DOM

Tags: jquery, events, ember.js

I'm using Emberjs with YUI for some reason, and I'm using the dataTable widget to generate my table automaticaly with the store of ember.

In this table I wanted to have a column with dynamic link to redirect to the good page for every row (like a detail page for every item in the table).

So I can't really use {{#link-to}} either the {{action}} helper because its generated in the js side.

So I thought to create a  and to catch the event in my view in ember.

I've found this :

```
App.Items = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function( event ) {
        var id = $(event.target).attr("value");
        this.get('controller').send('clickBtn', event, id);
    }
});
```

My button :

```
<button id="view-btn" value="{value}">View</button>
```

But the problem is like its listening for every event on my page... that kinda annoying because I just need it for one button..

Is it possible with ember to catch only the event from this button ?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

After some research I manage to find an other way to do this :

```
App.itemsView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log("didInsertElement done");
        this.$().on('click', '.view-btn', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
            console.log(id);
            //this.get('controller').send('clickBtn', event, id);
        });
    }
});
```

My button :

```
<button class="view-btn" data-value="{value}" data-action="open-enquiry">View</button>
```